# Why is Walter Jr. being called "Flynn"?

Tags: breaking-bad

Why is "Junior" in *Breaking Bad* all of a sudden now called Flynn?  I thought he was dubbed Junior as he is also Walter White (Jr.).  Is Flynn a middle name or second given name?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Walter Jr. starts calling himself "Flynn" in the [Season 2 episode "Down"](http://www.slantmagazine.com/house/2009/03/breaking-bad-mondays-season-2-ep-4-down/). He does it to distance himself from his father.

From [Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Breaking_Bad_characters#Walter_Hartwell_White_Jr.)

> **He grows apart from Walt due to his father's absences and bizarre behavior**, being taught to drive by his friends and **wanting to be called "Flynn**."

From a 2009 [interview with RJ Mitte (Walter Jr.)](http://blogs.amctv.com/breaking-bad/2009/05/rj-mitte-interview.php):

> **Q:** *Walter Jr. gives himself a nickname this season. Any idea where "Flynn" came from?**
>
> **A:** *I know it was an old movie star -- Errol Flynn. It took me a while to figure out where it came from though. I asked Vince, "Flynn? Out of all the nicknames?" And he's like "Well, that's why I picked it."*

Comment: He seemed to give up the nickname in season 3 during the period when Walt had moved out of the house. His mother called him "Flynn" during a family dinner and he angrily replied "My name is Walter Junior!" After that, "Flynn" wasn't heard again until the recent episodes where he's living with Hank and Marie. Why it's come back would be a good question. Maybe he's finally gotten tired of being on his dad's side in an argument he knows nothing about.

Answer (score 5):

Walter Jr decided that he didn't want to be called Walter White Jr as that's his dad's name and isn't cool. He was a teacher at the school his son goes to so I guess there is some pressure there.

There was never any reference to where it came from or why he chose it, I guess it's just different to Walter.

Answer (score 0):

It's because he still loves his dad and names himself after something his dad loves. (Flinn is a brand for chemistry)

Comment: Wips I meant it's because he still loves his dad and names himself Flynn because flinn is a reference to chemistry which his dad loves. But he wants to distinguish himself from his dad

Comment: If you'd like to edit your answer, use the edit button under the answer.

Comment: @CameronMonks add your comment to your answer. This is a bit of a stretch, but I can see it (if you include your comment)

Comment: Walter himself wonders what the heck is Flynn... So no way this could have been to do with chemistry.

Answer (score -5):

Walter Flynn Hartwell White Jr is his full name, when he is upset with dad he likes to be known as Flynn, i'm sure it will be Flynn from now on,  with that ending.... ;-)

Comment: Where did you get this?

Comment: From the breaking bad wiki. But there it's "Flynn", as in it's not part of his full name. This answer is just plain wrong.